# Does minReadySeconds work together with podManagementPolicy Parallel for a statefulset?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-statefulset

I would like the pod to wait some additional seconds before treat it as ready when rolling restart statefulset. I have searched the [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#minimum-ready-seconds), it says `minReadySeconds` is used to do so. But in my testing, if I set `podManagementPolicy` to `Parallel`, the `minReadySeconds` won't take effective. If I use the default `podManagementPolicy`, it can work. Is it expected?

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: web
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx # has to match .spec.template.metadata.labels
  serviceName: "nginx"
  replicas: 2 # by default is 1
  minReadySeconds: 30 # by default is 0
  podManagementPolicy: Parallel
  updateStrategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
```

I am testing it on k8s 1.24

Answer (score 0):

**MinReadySeconds** indicates how long will the pod be considered ready after it's updated. MinReadySeconds works with both OrderedReady and Parallel podManagementPolicy. It affects the pod scale up speed when the podManagementPolicy is set to be **OrderedReady** the default one

Another note:Combined with MaxUnavailable, it affects the pod update speed regardless of podManagementPolicy

Comment: Do you know any reason why MinReadySeconds doesn't work with Parallel podManagementPolicy? When I do a 'kubectl rollout restart statefulset mystatefulset' and watch the pod status, I see pod-0 was terminating as soon as pod-1 get ready.

Answer (score 0):

@leonard520 That is related to the **default recreate** deployment strategy of Kubernetes, it terminates the old pod the starts the new one sequentially. If you ever want to update it the way that it starts the termination of the old pod and the creation of the new one paralelly, you can update the deployment strategy  and replace it with **rollingUpdate with 1 maxSurge & 1 maxUnavailable** under spec section:

```
  strategy:
      rollingUpdate: 
        maxSurge: 1
        maxUnavailable: 1
      type: RollingUpdate
```

Here is an attached reference to deeply understand how deployment strategies exactly work & how you can manage them relating to the desired result: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LQI19ngeLsA